# Exact height of keyboard (with autoCorrect) in react-native on Android

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, react-native

I'm trying to get the height of the keyboard in order to scroll my view when it appears.  The *keyboardDidShow* event works perfectly in IOS, and the *height* value of the coordinates takes into account the extra bit that appears at the top of the keyboard when *autoCorrect* is on.

```
this.keyboardShowListener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
    'keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow);

...

keyboardDidShow (e) {
    let keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height;
    this.refs.mainScrollView.scrollTo(
        {x: 0, y: keyboardHeight, animated: true});
},
```

However, in Android (with NR 0.21.0) it looks like the value given for the height doesn't include the extra *auto-correct* component height, and so when I scroll it comes up a bit short.

Now I could just add on some value for android, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.  Can you be sure it works on every android keyboard?  I suspect not.

So, is there a way to get a handle on the keyboard object in order to  measure it?

Comment: I've realised that this code is only necessary in IOS.  If I wrap my view in a ScrollView then android automatically scrolls it when the keyboard appears.  The problem is though that it doesn't scroll it the correct amount.  Some of the keyboard is rendered on top of the bottom of my view.

Answer (score -4):

For android, the setting for `android:windowSoftInputMode` is magic, it could affect the behaviour of keyboard, thus keyboard event.